# É possível usar Razor dentro de arquivo Javascript?

Tags: javascript, razor

Tenho um arquivo `.js` e gostaria de usar a sintaxe do `Razor` dentro dele.

Tentei usar simplesmente o `@` mas não funcionou.

Existe alguma possibilidade? Alguém pode me ajudar? Já pesquisei bastante, mas não encontro nada...

Comment: Já tentou utilizar RazorJS?
http://nuget.org/List/Packages/RazorJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direto no .js não tem como, o que você pode fazer é instanciar sua classe no html/razor, pois assim você consegue setar valores no javascript e passar como parametro da classe por exemplo...

Tem o lado ruim, é que precisa fazer isso direto na página, mas resolve o problema.

Exemplo:

Imagine que seu .js é algo como:

```
var MeuObjetoJs = function(minhasVariaveis){
  //Faz o que tem que fazer...
}
```

Ai na sua página razor, **após** vc carregar o script .js você coloca:

```
<script>
  var minhasVariaveis = {
    minhaVariavelUm: '@Model.MinhaVariavelUm',
    minhaVariavelDois: '@Model.MinhaVariavelDois'
  }
  var meuObjetoJs = new MeuObjetoJs(minhasVariaveis);
</script>
```

Ai no seu .js, você acessaria normalmente com:

```
minhasVariaveis.MinhaVariavelUm
minhasVariaveis.MinhaVariavelDois
```

E assim por diante...